# Regex - Parse string by removing characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I am trying to parse the path part of a url.

The input, is a string such as `site/whatever%  ^&*/page/to-days_date//` which I would like to convert into `site/whatever/page/to-days_date`

Things to *remove* would be anything that is *not* one of the following:

1. lower or upper case letter
2. digit / number
3. dash
4. underscore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `/+$` with a pipe(`|`) with your existing regex. It means match any number(starting from 1) of `/` from the end of input. So it will work for `/` `//` or `/////` at the end of the input.

```
myString = '''blog/whatever%  ^&*/page/to-days_date//'''
print re.sub(r'/+$|[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-\/]+', '', myString)
               ^^^ here
```

Comment: Probably this will work `/+$|[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-\/]+|/(?=/)`. Basically using `/(?=/)` it is checking if the `/` is followed by another `/`, then remove it :-)